# Doctrine2 OneToOne relationship with primary key as a foreign one without eager loading

Tags: doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, eager-loading, one-to-one

I have 2 entities: User and ResetToken (which used to reset password) so I want to have relations on them like:

```
$token->getUser();
$user->getToken();
```

One user has always max one token, so I want to have token's pk to be fk as well, and doctrine 2 is allowed us to do that, but it forces me to have an eager loading when I'm fetching user any time.

Is there way to make OneToOne **bidirectional** relation without eager loading at least for User entity?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for but a 1:1 unidirectional relation is probably what you want: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional  If the link does not help then update your question with the relevant mappings.

Comment: Well I need a bidirectional one, to be able to execute methods that I've listed, but when I do bidirectional relation one of sides should be owning one, it's ResetToken since it has "foreign key" to User, but when I do that, Doctrine 2 always fetches User model within ResetToken, but I need it to be lazy loading

Comment: Maybe post your mappings.  As @Veve said below, lazy loading is the default.  Maybe you have something else going on.  And I wonder if you really need this to be bidirectional.  It would seem that needing a reset token would be an infrequent requirement and worth making an explicit query for.